# Compare two list with dicts and print out value that is not in the list using Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been trying to play abit with two list that includes dicts. Basically I have two list that are following:

```
listA = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]
listB = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]
```

What I try to achieve here is that I want to compare listA with listB and print out whatever that is not in listB from listA. In our case we don't have `{'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}`in listB meaning in that case the output would be:

```
{'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}
```

However I did not found any similar to my problem due to I have "comma" inside a dict. (maybe it is not a correct of dicts??)

I would appreciate every sort of help to solve my issue of printing out the dicts that are not in listB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Use **loop** to iterate each element in `listA` and **if-statement** to compare it with all elements in `listB`:

```
listA = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]
listB = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]

for A in listA:
    if A not in listB:
        print(A)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}
```

Comment: I do believe this is the answer I might have been looking for due to it does actually print one by one for each dicts that is not in each list. I do believe I will mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Great, happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

you can approach this problem with a `O(n^2)` complexity by using `in` in a loop (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55886152/6451573) answer), but you can also rebuild `listB` as a set of `tuples` to reduce complexity to `O(n)` (you need to transform dictionaries into tuples so they can be added in a `set`):

```
listA = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]
listB = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]

listB = {tuple(x.items()) for x in listB}

difference = [A for A in listA if tuple(A.items()) not in listB]
```

result:

```
>>> difference
[{'color': 'Blue', 'name': 'ColorB'}]
```

`tuple(A.items()) not in listB` has to build a `tuple` each time, but after that `not in` operation is `O(1)`

Comment: Oh alright, as you said. However this might seem abit too complicated for me not knowing what a tuples actually does so I need to google it first. I do also wanted to print each dicts one by one for those that are not in each others list as this answer here  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886127/compare-two-list-with-dicts-and-print-out-value-that-is-not-in-the-list-using-py/55886152#55886152) - However if I might ask you while you are here, what is the difference if you made the code printing out one by one dicts that are not in listB?

Comment: you can use a classic loop and print too instead of list comprehension, no difference. Creating `tuple` of the key+value allows to make the data _hashable_ and thus you're able to put them in a `set` for quick testing

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> listA = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]
>>> listB = [{'name': 'ColorR', 'color': 'Red'}, {'name': 'ColorP', 'color': 'Purple'}, {'name': 'ColorO', 'color': 'Orange'}, {'name': 'ColorW', 'color': 'White'}]
>>> [item for item in listA if item not in listB]
[{'name': 'ColorB', 'color': 'Blue'}]
>>>
```